# Doubt about “put ‘something’ behind”

Tags: word-in-context

I’ve seen some uses of **“put ‘something’ behind”** with a pronoum (not really sure if it’s a pronoum) after “behind” and other without. Here are some examples:

You should put those bad memories **behind you** and start focusing on the good life you have now.

Let's just put this loss **behind us** and start preparing for the next game.

Clear skies are ahead so put your troubles **behind** and be happy.

That way, you'll be able to put your concerns **behind** and get on with something even more important.

Do they all have the same meaning? Are there cases where the use of you, us, etc is necessary and others don’t?

Comment: I've never heard it without a pronoun. Where have you seen example of that?

Comment: I really don't know if they are pronouns. In the first two examples above the sentences the word "behind" have "you" (from "behind you") and "us" (from "behind us") after them and in the last two ones it's just "behind" without "you", "us", etc.

Comment: Yes, they are pronouns. 'Leave your troubles behind' is idiomatic, 'put them behind' sounds odd.